# CakePHP, table $belongsTo two table: error Error: Cannot redeclare table::$belongsTo

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp

I have problem like that - have 3 tables, for example Clients, Hats, Tshirts. Each Client have one Hat and one Tshirt relation. I made this like that:

```
 `
  ClientsModel:
  var $name = 'Client';
  var $belongsTo = 'Hat';
  var $belongsTo = 'Tshirt';

  HatModel:
  var $name = 'Hat';
  var $hasMany = 'Client';

  TshirtModel:
  var $name = 'Tshirt';
  var $hasMany = 'Client';
  `
```

I cant display indext.ctp of Clients View, the error is:
        `
       Fatal Error

```
   Error: Cannot redeclare Cleint::$belongsTo
   File: /var/www/uat/app/Model/Client.php 
   `
```

How to deal with that relation in my database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To declare a belongsTo relation you need to create an array of object not a single var for each belongsTo relation.
In your you client Model the belongsTo relation needs to be like this:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Hat' => array(
        'className'     => 'Hat',
        'conditions'    => '',
        'order'         => '',
        'foreignKey'    => 'hat_id' //or your external key
    ),
    'Tshirt' => array(
        'className'     => 'Tshirt',
        'conditions'    => '',
        'order'         => '',
        'foreignKey'    => 'tshirt_id' //or your external key
    )
);
```

[**MANUAL**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html)

Comment: Thank You!!!!! I have change that, and it works perfectly!!
but have next problem:
      `
       .../cakephp/Clients/add is not working for 100%.
       `

My drop down list in add.ctp is not diplay Hats names, but only number, 1, 2, 3...etc. Why?

Comment: It depends of your code to find values. accept this answer and open another with the new problem :) @tomas3man

Comment: Ok i will open new question now to show the problem.